# Unable to multiply two matrices (double[][] arrays)

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

What I am attempting to do is using a method which is part of a constructed object (it shows us as `Matrix.getArray()`). It is a `double[][]` essentially. However I need to multiply 2 of my constructed `Matrix` and it must be done this way unfortunately due to some constraints. So I am wondering how to get the scope of the selected `Matrix` in question.

Here is some code to better illustrate what I mean:

```
Matrix matA = new Matrix(arrayA);
Matrix matB = new Matrix(arrayB);

matA.mulBy(matB);
```

This is part of my `main()` class that will launch the program, calling on `matA`'s `mulBy` method which will multiply it by `matB`. However I cannot get it to work as I cannot select the indices of `matA` in scope to multiply, as is shown below:

```
public Matrix mulBy(Matrix A)
{
    double[][] arrayC = new double[getRows()][A.getColumns()];
    double[][] mulArray = A.getArray();
    System.out.println(leng);
    System.out.println(widt);
    for(int f = 0; f < A.getColumns(); f++)
    {
    //must add F loop here
        for(int i = 0; i < A.getColumns(); i++)
        {
            arrayC[i][f] = m[i][0] * mulArray[0][i];
        }
    }

    Matrix matC = new Matrix(arrayC);

    return matC;
}
```

So I guess the question is, how do I multiply these to make this work? Or how do I even get that `Matrix`'s incides within scope to work with them? How do I access the variables of `matA` to make this work?

I have been unable to word this properly and find resources online as I am unaware of the terminology required to describe this.

Comment: You should probably check that *number of columns on left matrix = number of rows on right matrix* and throw an exception if not true. Also, add debug statements in your code to see how far you're getting.

Comment: How would you do this with pencil and paper??

Comment: Code seems to work when all of the other stuff is thrown in here. It's very crude at this point, but I just need to know how to get the matA to be in scope to multiply it by MatB to create MatC.

Comment: What do you mean by "the scope of the second Matrix"? It looks like you already know how to retrieve the contents of a second Matrix (called `A` in your function), along with its row and column sizes. What do you need that isn't already there?

Comment: I mean it is invoked by matA.mulBy(matB);. B is passed to the method as Matrix A(sorry, that's awfully confusing). Matrix A I can manipulate as I please, however I don't know how to multiply it's values against the values of matA that is used when the method is invoked.

MatA is created by a constructor that creates a "Matrix". mulBy() is a method within the "Matrix" class and is invoked by Matrix.mulBy(). I just cannot manipulate the matrix that is used to invoke the method. The one passed to the method as a parameter is fine.

Comment: I don't get it. If you are invoking like `matA.mulBy(matB)` then from the perspective of `mulBy`, you are inside `matA`, Is your question really "how to access an object from inside itself"?

Comment: What is `m[i][0]`? Isn't that the content of `matA`?

Answer (score 0):

To reference an Object from inside itself you must use the keyword `this`, for example :

```
Class Matrix {

    private double[][] myArray;

    public Matrix() {...} // Constructor

    public Matrix mulBy(Matrix A) {

        double[][] arrayC = new double[getRows()][A.getColumns()];
        double[][] mulArray = A.getArray();
        System.out.println(leng);
        System.out.println(widt);
        for(int f = 0; f < A.getColumns(); f++)
        {
        //must add F loop here
            for(int i = 0; i < A.getColumns(); i++)
            {
                // to access myArray of the object that you are calling it's method use this
                arrayC[i][f] = this.myArray[i][0] * mulArray[0][i];
            }
        }

        Matrix matC = new Matrix(arrayC);

        return matC;
    }
}
```

In this case, even if you remove the `this` keyword it'll work, because you don't have any other variable in the scope of you method that have the same name.

But if we replace `myArray` with `arrayC` (for example) in this case we must use `this.arrayC` to differentiate the local variable from the instance variable.